# I need to know why my Transition effect not working for input:checked::before

Tags: html, css, input, checked

I want to give transition effect to the before element of input when
checked but it's not working.

I need to know why this is not working.
Or else I have to try something new

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin: 13px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked::before{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
}

input[type="checkbox"]::before{
  content: '';
  width: 75px;
  height: 44px;
  right: 100;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 1px;
  transition: 0.5s ;    
}

div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition you are missing stuff in the transition declaration

Comment: Also, the `right` property needs units.

Comment: @Sean thanks for your tip

Answer (score 1):

A couple things here:

Your right value needed "px" and move `transition: 0.5s linear;` to your `input[type="checkbox"]::before`.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin: 13px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: lightcoral;
  width: 75px;
  height: 44px;
  /* calculate right 100% minus width of :before to get correct position */
  right: calc(100% - 75px);;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked::before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
```